# Making UIWebView behave like a native view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

There are an increasing number of apps that use UIWebView in the app, like LikeALittle. Instagram's "Notes" view also uses UIWebview, and it behaves stunningly similar to the native view.

What customizations do you need to make to the JS, and are there any best practices or tutorials for achieving a good native-like UX in the UIWebview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the severals framework created with mobile propose, like JQuery Mobile, JQTouch or Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)